# Pure OpenGL CoverFlow implementation--not iPhone or OpenGL ES or other toolkit

Tags: opengl, coverflow

Are there any open-source implementations of CoverFlow that are pure OpenGL, and not dependent on one of the following:

1. Any iOS or Apple API
2. OpenGL ES--I want this to run on a desktop, not a mobile device
3. Not tied to other toolkits, such as Qt, Gtk, etc.

I've not been able to find anything fitting this description, which is very surprising to me.

Comment: OpenGL ES API is in fact a subset of OpenGL API.

Comment: Another thing to know is that OpenGL  standard says nothing about initialization, so opening a window (if you have a window system) and initializing it for OpenGL is system-dependent. There are plenty of intermediate layers to simplify the task -- e.g. GLUT. Most GUI frameworks include GL initialization utilities too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question and tell what language and environment are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not really a pure OpenGL, it is based on GLScene - GLScene is an OpenGL based 3D library for Delphi - it is called CoverFrame.

You didn't specify the language, so I suggest you this which is for Delphi (Pascal).

[image]

It is free for use in any project. Read the license or mail to the author.

- You can also control:
  Mirror alpha
  Transparency
  Horizontal / Vertical

Demo and SourceCode [here](http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/06/coverflow-update.html)